# How to capture only the fields modified by user

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to build a logging mechanism, to log changes done to a record. I am currently logging previous and new record. However, as the site is very busy, I expect the logfile to grow seriously huge. To avoid this, I plan to only capture the modified fields only. 
Is there a way to capture only the modifications done to a record (in REACT), so my {request.body} will have fewer fields?

My Server-side is build with NODE.JS and the client-side is REACT.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you might want to consider is to add an onChange(universal) or onTextChanged(native) listener to the text field and store the form update in a local state/variables.

Finally, when a user makes an action (submit, etc.) you can send the updated data to the logging module.

Comment: Your reply gave me an idea.... I will save the original record in state with a different name and in the onSubmit method, I will analyse the difference and then build the object to send in the request body. would this be a better idea?

Comment: for example: `/**

 * Deep diff between two object, using lodash

 * @param  {Object} object Object compared

 * @param  {Object} base   Object to compare with

 * @return {Object}        Return a new object who represent the diff

 */

function difference(object, base) {

 function changes(object, base) {

  return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {

   if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {

    result[key] = (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) ? changes(value, base[key]) : value;

   }

  });

 }

 return changes(object, base);

}`

Comment: You could create a state for each of your field that you could populate with onChange to their input. 
Then when you send data to back end, you could check each state of your input if empty or not before sending.

Comment: you can also set two state parameters: 1. `currentFieldValue` 2. `formModifiedFieldList`. Then send the updated fields based on the keys of (2.). (1.) is not really necessary for this task, but it will most likely be required for form validation so is a nice to have if your page performance allows it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found and works for me is …

on the api server-side, where I handle the update request, before hitting the database, I do a difference between the previous record and {request.body} using lodash and use the result to send to my update database function

```
var _ = require('lodash');
const difference = (object, base) => {
function changes(object, base) {
    return _.transform(object, function (result, value, key) {
      if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {
        result[key] = (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) ? changes(value, base[key]) : value;
      }
    });
  }
  return changes(object, base);
}
module.exports = difference
```

I saved the above code in a file named diff.js and included it in my server-side file. 
It worked good.

Thanks for giving the idea...